# mysql join question

Tags: mysql, date, join

This is probably really easy, but I am having trouble with it. I asked a question earlier ([MySql Query help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845775/mysql-query-help)) about a query and the answer was to create another table and join it with my current query. So I am creating a temporary table and joining it with my query but am getting the same results.

Overview: 
I have a dates tables with the dates for the last 30 days and a value of 0 for every entry

```
+------+------------+
| Zero | Date       |
+------+------------+
|    0 | 2011-07-27 |
|    0 | 2011-07-26 |
|    0 | 2011-07-25 |
|    0 | 2011-07-24 |
|    0 | 2011-07-23 |
|    0 | 2011-07-22 |
...etc
```

And I am trying to join this table with a query I do another table that gets these results:

```
+-------------------+-----------+
| Past-Month-Builds | Month-Day |
+-------------------+-----------+
|                53 | 6-27      |
|               103 | 6-28      |
|                91 | 6-29      |
|                70 | 6-30      |
|                76 | 7-1       |
|                 8 | 7-2       |
|                77 | 7-5       |
|               111 | 7-6       |
|                67 | 7-7       |
|                70 | 7-8       |
|                 2 | 7-9       |
|                 3 | 7-10      |
|                87 | 7-11      |
|                53 | 7-12      |
|                49 | 7-13      |
|                84 | 7-14      |
|               126 | 7-15      |
|                 3 | 7-16      |
|                 8 | 7-17      |
|                98 | 7-18      |
|               114 | 7-19      |
|               841 | 7-20      |
|               206 | 7-21      |
|               738 | 7-22      |
|                 2 | 7-23      |
|                65 | 7-25      |
|                39 | 7-26      |
|                21 | 7-27      |
+-------------------+-----------+
```

Notice that there are missing days, I would like the Past-Month-Builds Col to display 0 when there weren't any builds on that day.

Here is the query I am trying to use:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS 'Past-Month-Builds',
    CONCAT(MONTH(builds.submittime), '-', DAY(builds.submittime)) as 'Month-Day'
FROM builds
    RIGHT JOIN dates ON DATE(builds.submittime) = dates.Date
WHERE DATE(builds.submittime) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 day)
GROUP BY MONTH(submittime), DAY(submittime);
```

Kinda lost, any help would be great
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query so `dates` is the primary table and use a `left outer join` to the `builds` table.

Also, move any criteria related to the builds table from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause since that's the optional table.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Right after I submitted this I looked over the query again and was like..Why am I doing a Right Join...Thanks